# Max-height attribute makes image unproportional wide in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have set an image with the css set to a max-height of 220px and a height of 100%.

That should set (this) image width to 175px and height to 220px. Which works fluently in Firefox and Internet explorer but in Chrome (desktop, tablet & smartphone) it sets the height to 220px but the width(!) to 220px as well. Why is this, **is this some kind of bug in Chrome or am I just missing something here**.

Weird part is, that if you'll remove the height:100% part so you are only left with the max-height:220px, this problem does not occur.

See a more detailed example below
[image: Detailed example]

```
figure {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 220px;
}

a {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height:220px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/be5jT/ JS Fiddle Example

Comment: The guy in the picture simply gained a lot of weight when viewed in chrome. I haven't tried it but you can try setting a max-width on the image so the weight gaining could stop.

Comment: adding max-width should do the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What's Going On:

If you use the inspector tool, the browsers are adding `width:auto;`, because no width rules are declared. I've researched a bit and I can't find any reason as to WHY, but it comes down the fact that Chrome and Firefox calculated "width:auto" differently. Firefox is calculating based on proportional, and Chrome is displaying native.

[image]

[image]

I've checked the CSS2.1 Width spec, and since we are talking about an image which is inline, we have a large number of conditions to check for. The one that I think applies here is:

> Otherwise, if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', and the element
>   has an intrinsic width, then that intrinsic width is the used value of
>   'width'.
>
> Source - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width

If I'm reading it right, that means that Chrome is technically correct, even though Firefox's method ends up looking better.

### Alternative Fix Method:

lili2311's answer will work, but then you'd have to declare the width, which means that you'd have to use images which are the same proportions. You could also remove the ``` height:``00% ```, which you already know. A third method would be to give the `a` a `height:100%`, change the `max-height:220px` to `height:220px` on the `figure`, and then remove the `max-height` from the `img`. This lets you only declare `220px` once.

#### Code:

```
figure {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
}
a {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

#### Working Demo: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Can you explain the discrepancy between Chrome and other browsers?

Comment: Added, as much as I can determine.

Comment: Excellent, I think that covers it.

Answer (score 1):

You no need to add `height`, set `max-height` only

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/be5jT/6/)

```
img {
    max-height:220px;
}
```

Comment: This will not do the exact same thing, since it will not make images  smaller then 220px stretch up. You could argue that you should not do that anyway with jpeg but images can contain SVG as well : )

Answer (score 0):

Setting max-width as well fixed the issue for me in Chrome:

```
img {
    max-height:220px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width:175px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/be5jT/2/

Comment: Surely this will only work for images with the same aspect ratio. A different ratio and the images will get stretched or squashed.

Comment: This was specific to OPs image but for images of any size, if they should not get stretched something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/lili2311/be5jT/10/)